# SDL 2 program uses 1.4 GB of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, sdl, sdl-2

Okay, so I've been working on this little bouncing DVD logo thingy and I'm running to it slowly taking up more and more memory. Eventually it ends up taking a whopping 1.4 GB then slows down and crashes. Here is the code, what is wrong with it that causes it to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2_image/SDL_image.h>
// This sets ups the display.
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("DVD Thingy", 100, 100,
                                        800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
                                        | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED
                                        | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
SDL_Renderer* screen = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

void drawText(char text[], int origX, int origY, SDL_Renderer* ren, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color color) {
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, text, color);
    SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, surfaceMessage);
    int w = surfaceMessage->w;
    int h = surfaceMessage->h;
    SDL_Rect messageRect = {origX, origY, w, h};
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, Message, NULL, &messageRect);

    SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
}

int main() {
    // This initializes the font class.
    srand(time(NULL));
   TTF_Init();
   int skyboxColor = 240;
   bool done = false;
   int dirX = 1, dirY = 1;
   TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("./Impact.ttf", 18);
   TTF_SetFontOutline(font, 1);
   int dvdX = rand() % 800, dvdY = rand() % 600-20;
   SDL_Color white = {255, 255, 255};
   SDL_Event event;
   while (!done) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    SDL_Quit();
                    return 0;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        dvdX += dirX;
        dvdY += dirY;
        if (dvdX > 770) {
            dirX = -1;
        }
        if (dvdX < 0) {
            dirX = 1;
        }
        if (dvdY < -3) {
            dirY = 1;
        }
        if (dvdY > 580) {
            dirY = -1;
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( screen, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(screen);
        drawText("DVD", dvdX, dvdY, screen, font, white);
        SDL_RenderPresent(screen);
        SDL_Delay (1/1000 * 60);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. If you're on Linux, run Valgrind or similar and it should show you where the memory leak is (if you have one).

Comment: `The caller (you!) is responsible for freeing any returned surface.` - http://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf_44.html

Comment: `SDL_Delay (1/1000 * 60);` will always pass 0.  `1000 / desiredFPS` is more likely what you want, although it doesn't take into account how long any processing since the last frame took.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that in the `drawText()` function you are creating a new SDL_Surface by means of a call to TTF_RenderText_Blended().

You must ensure to free this surface when you are finished with it, which would appear to be at the end of the function it is created in. You already destroy the texture which you create from the surface so all you need to add is one line after that:

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);   <- Free the surface
```

As `drawText()` was being called constantly in the main while loop, it was bloating memory with SDL_Surfaces.

Just one other point, as you don't seem to be changing the text from "DVD" you could create the texture once and then just draw it where ever you need to. This would be much more efficient than creating, drawing and then destroying every single drame.